# What is better: use find_in_set OR built another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have an app with users and clients.
I need to create permissions for each user If he has access to all clients or some of them.

I am confused between:

- adding a new comma separated column to users table, which requires using **FIND_IN_SET** function when I check existence,
- creating permissions table with client_id and user_id Which requires **SELECT and WHERE** methods only.

Can you help me decide what's better for performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are using Relational Database. There is something called **First Normal Form [1NF]**

I strongly recommend to read about [Database Normalization](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/):

> A database is in first normal form if it satisfies the following
>   conditions:
>
> **Contains only atomic values**
>
> There are no repeating groups

and:

> **An atomic value is a value that cannot be divided.**

So instead of adding new column with comma separated values create new table.

Comment: Is that still true even if I queried column with MYSQL (like option 1) then explode result with PHP function?

Comment: @ahmed Yes, that still true. In Relational World you should choose Normalized Form over compound values.